# Trying to count the time passed between a start and stop events in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, events, time, active-directory

I am trying to obtain the difference in time between each start and stop action in the following output:

```
User    Computer   Time                Event      Action
----    --------   ----                -----      ------
TEST\me TEST-DC-01 27/05/2020 14:45:06 Logoff     Stop
TEST\me TEST-DC-01 27/05/2020 14:44:56 Unlock     Start
TEST\me TEST-DC-01 27/05/2020 14:44:49 Lock       Stop
TEST\me TEST-DC-01 27/05/2020 14:44:40 Reconnect  Start
TEST\me TEST-DC-01 27/05/2020 14:43:17 Disconnect Stop
TEST\me TEST-DC-01 27/05/2020 14:43:07 Logon      Start
```

I've been playing with the New-Timespan cmdlet but seem to be going round and round in circles when trying to integrate it with the script (below) which the above output is derived from.

Ideally, I'd like to see the following appended to it:

```
Total active time: 00:00:29
```

Can anyone advise on the best approach (either by fully integrating with the existing script or by importing the output in CSV format).

Any guidance most appreciated.

```
#
# GROUP POLICY (TO ENABLE 480x AND 477x EVENTS):
# 
#   COMPUTER CONFIGURATION
#   -  WINDOWS SETTINGS
#      -  SECURITY SETTINGS
#         -  ADVANCED AUDIT POLICY CONFIGURATION
#            -  SYSTEM AUDIT POLICIES - LOCAL GROUP POLICY OBJECT
#               -  LOGON/LOGOFF
#                  -  AUDIT OTHER LOGON/LOGOFF EVENTS
#                     -  SUCCESS
#
$OU = "OU=Domain Controllers,DC=test,DC=local"
   # WHERE TO SEARCH FOR COMPUTERS IN ACTIVE DIRECTORY
$days = "-1"
   # HOW MANY DAYS TO SEARCH BACK THROUGH
$directory = "C:\"
   # LOCATION OF FAILED CONNECTIONS FILE
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OU
$logs = @()
$timestamp = ((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))
$output = ForEach ($computer in $computers){
   try{
      $logs += get-eventlog `
         -LogName system `
         -ComputerName $computer.Name `
         -After (Get-Date).AddDays($days) 
      $logs += get-eventlog `
         -LogName security `
         -ComputerName $computer.Name `
         -After (Get-Date).AddDays($days)
      $res = @()
      ForEach ($log in $logs){
         if($log.instanceid -eq 7001){
            $type = "Logon"
            $user = 
               try{
                  (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(
                     $log.ReplacementStrings[1])).Translate(
                     [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value
               }
               catch{
                  $log.ReplacementStrings[1]
               }
            $action = "Start"
         }
         Elseif ($log.instanceid -eq 7002){
            $type = "Logoff"
            $user = 
               try{
                  (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(
                     $log.ReplacementStrings[1])).Translate(
                     [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value
               }
               catch{
                  $log.ReplacementStrings[1]
               }
            $action = "Stop"
         }
         Elseif ($log.instanceid -eq 4800){
            $type = "Lock"
            $user = $log.ReplacementStrings[2] + "\" + 
               $log.ReplacementStrings[1]
            $action = "Stop"
         }
         Elseif ($log.instanceid -eq 4801){
            $type = "Unlock"
            $user = $log.ReplacementStrings[2] + "\" + 
               $log.ReplacementStrings[1]
            $action = "Start"
         }
         Elseif ($log.instanceid -eq 4778){
            $type = "Reconnect"
            $user = $log.ReplacementStrings[1] + "\" + 
               $log.ReplacementStrings[0]
            $action = "Start"
         }
         Elseif ($log.instanceid -eq 4779){
            $type = "Disconnect"
            $user = $log.ReplacementStrings[1] + "\" + 
               $log.ReplacementStrings[0]
            $action = "Stop"
         }
         Else {
            Continue
         }
         $hash = [ordered]@{
            "User" = $user
            "Computer" = $computer.Name
            "Time" = $log.TimeWritten
            "Event" = $type
            "Action" = $action
         }
         $res += New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
      }
      $res
   }
   Catch {
      Add-Content -Path "${directory}${timestamp}_failed.txt" $computer.Name
   }
}
$TimeDescending = @{
   Expression = 'Time'
   Descending = $true
}
$EventDescending = @{
   Expression = 'Event'
   Descending = $true
}
$output |
   sort User,Computer,$TimeDescending,$EventDescending |
   ? User -like "*me" |
   ft
```

Comment: `$stopEvent.Time - $startEvent.Time` will give you the difference

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for the response.  I'm not sure I follow, sorry.  Where do I get those variables from?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `New-TimeSpan` cmdlet:

```bsh
$start = Get-Date

# Do some stuff here

$end = Get-Date

$timeTaken = (New-TimeSpan -Start $start -End $end).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: Hi Retry, thanks for the suggestion.

Based on the output at the top this page being exported to a CSV and then imported by another script (I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it all in one go but I'm trying to break it up initially as it's easier for me to chew on!), how can I get that script to find the first "stop" after a "start", calculate the difference, hold that value, repeat from the next start and then calculate a total at the end.

I know what I'm trying to say, just not sure of how to formulate it.

Comment: I have attempted an alternative solution as an interim measure to try and visualise what I want to do in PowerShell by utilizing Excel.

If I drop the following formula in to cell F3 (if the above output is imported in to Excel, cell F3 would be to the right of the uppermost "Stop" - would be much easier to drop a screenshot but can't seem to be able to) and then drag down with a total at the bottom I get what I want.

=IF(E3="Stop",SUM(C3-C4),0)

Excuse the crudity of my attempt.  Any way of emulating this with PowerShell?